# How to create a jquery function that affect id with prefix and suffix?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I need to record like a timetable, day by day. Let's say I have this jQuery to calculate or do something

```
$('#report_time_hours').change(function() {
    $('[name=reporttime]').val(/* new value */);
});
$('#report_time_minutes').keyup(function() {
    $('[name=reporttime]').val(/* new value */);
});
$('#report_time_period').change(function() {
    $('[name=reporttime]').val(/* new value */);
});
```

these functions is considered as a set of function for a day.

I have 7 days (Mon to Sun), and in the HTML part, I should rename the ids and name by adding prefix to it like `mon_reportname`, `mon_report_time_hours`, `sun_report_time_hours` etc...

If I use

```
$('[id$=_report_time_hours]')
```

This will surely affect all field with ids of that suffix, regardless of the prefix (mon, tue etc.)

So, how can I make the set of function only affect similar prefix?

Comment: can you share the html sample

Comment: How about giving all of those elements a class name too / instead?

Comment: Do you mean like adding class="Monday"? Btw, to make it clear, I'm trying to avoid making 7 sets of functions for each day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give Your Id's Numbers For Example :

```
$('#report_time_hours1').change(function() {
    $('[name=reporttime]').val(/* new value */);
});
$('#report_time_minutes1').keyup(function() {
    $('[name=reporttime]').val(/* new value */);
});
$('#report_time_period1').change(function() {
    $('[name=reporttime]').val(/* new value */);
});
```

and then u can represent each day as a number 1 - Sunday and etc.

Then your code should look like this :

```
for(i=1;i<=7 ; i++)
{
    $('#report_time_hours' + i).change(function() {
        $('[name=reporttime]').val(/* new value */);
    });
    $('#report_time_minutes1' + i).keyup(function() {
        $('[name=reporttime]').val(/* new value */);
    });
    $('#report_time_period1' + i).change(function() {
        $('[name=reporttime]').val(/* new value */);
    }); 
}
```

this should do the trick.

Although i would go for a class for all your data and then it should be much simpler:

```
    $('classForHours').change(function() {
        $('[name=reporttime]').val(/* new value */);
    });
    $('classForMinutes').keyup(function() {
        $('[name=reporttime]').val(/* new value */);
    });
    $('classForPeriods' + i).change(function() {
        $('[name=reporttime]').val(/* new value */);
    });
```

This also will do the trick

Comment: oh yeah, number. why didn't that come to my mind (-_-). But, can you explain more about the class part? Anyway, thanks.

Comment: yes when you give a class for your hours for example they do the same thing so when you are searching this in jquery $('.className') this will hive you an array of all the dom elments with this className then you can attach the change to this array and all of your dom elments with that class will get this change.

Comment: So, now, I can put it into a loop using $('.className[i]'), right? Sorry I'm a bit slow in understanding this. EDIT: it should be  $('.className:eq(i)'), right? OK, Thank you!